# What are the prerequisites for a question to be transferred over to Super User?

Tags: support, questions, migration

Two questions really:

1. What are the prerequisites for a question to be migrated over to Super User part of Stack Exchange?
2. Why was my question migrated over from Stack Overflow to SuperUser, if the first question is answered, I'm sure this will be redundant, but I'm curious more than anything.

Here is the link.

- [Is there a way through an excel formula to have it where a blank cell and a specific value show 0?](https://superuser.com/questions/478452/is-there-a-way-through-an-excel-formula-to-have-it-where-a-blank-cell-and-a-spec)

Answer (score 6):

1. - Your question **must be on topic on the destination site** (in this case Super User) *and*
   - **your question is not too old** *and*
   - your **question is not crap** *and*
   - any of the following:

     - you **requested a migration** to a different site (e.g. to get more exposure) *or*
     - **your question is off topic on the original site**.
2. See above. It was considered *off topic* on Stack Overflow, as use of simple Excel functions isn't considered programming.

Comment: Plus, the question shouldn't be too old, with no real numbers on what defines "old" here, but two years is definitely a no-go.

Comment: @slhck Of course, all of these requirements go right out the window with community voted migrations, especially from SO.